# Input style in HTML

Tags: html, css, input, label

I have this structure:

```
<div class="right"><div class="button"><a class="go-button green" href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><span>SHOP</span></a></div>
            </div>
                <div class="center"><div class="button"><a class="go-button green" href="<?php echo $continue; ?>"><span>SHOP 2</span></a></div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.button {
    display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0s 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0s 0;
  -ms-transition: all 0s 0;
  -o-transition: all 0s 0;
  transition: all 0s 0;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #42af92;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  cursor: pointer !important;

}

a.go-button {
    height: 35px;

/../
```

This structure is working. But i have this input:

```
<div class="input cf">
                        <input type="submit" name="reg-submit" id="reg-submit" value="Kaydı Tamamla" class="button">
                    </div>
```

And want this style like before divs. How can i import/embed this input in `div button`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. Just apply the style to multiple selectors, like this:

```
div.button, #reg-submit {
display: inline-block;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-transition: all 0s 0;
-moz-transition: all 0s 0;
-ms-transition: all 0s 0;
-o-transition: all 0s 0;
transition: all 0s 0;
text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #42af92;
padding: 5px 15px;
margin: 5px 0px;
color: #fff !important;
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
cursor: pointer !important;

}
```